# Intersection of two fields

Tags: field-theory

I am doing a qus and stuck at one step....
Qus- let F1 & F2 are two subfield of a finitefield F consisting of 2^9 and 2^6 elemnt...then total no. Of elemnt in F1 intersection F2.

According to me F1∩F2 is also field contained in F1 and F2 so choices  of F1∩F2 is 2¹ and 2² but its answer only 2² why?

Comment: Should your $2^2$ both be $2^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nonzero elements of $F_1$ are the roots of $x^{2^9-1}=1$.

The nonzero elements of $F_2$ are the roots of $x^{2^6-1}=1$.

Therefore, the nonzero elements of $F_1 \cap F_2 $ are the roots of $x^{n}=1$, where $n=\gcd(2^9-1, 2^6-1)=7=2^3-1$.

Comment: As i know that group of order $2^{9}-1$ will be cyclic because of property(because $F_1$ is field),but can you please elaborate why nonzero elemnts of $F_1$ is roots of $x^{2^{9}-1}=1$,

Comment: @TheStudent, Lagrange's theorem applied to the multiplicative group $F_1^\times$

Comment: Group of order $2^{9}-1$ is cyclic so every element raise to power order of group is identity am i right? but instead of $1$ can we use $e$ because we don't know about indentity?

Answer (score 0):

A field F of order p^{n} contains another field of order p^{d} if and only if d divides n.